# React app, http-proxy-middleware and axios proxy to backend server (production and development)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, proxy, axios

What I want is to work proxy in both production and as well development.
Whenever I try to make `POST` request, I get

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

It looks like proxy isn't working.

example Backend url
`https://backend-example.com/api/create`

**Sample request function**

```
export const create = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await api.post(`/api/create`)
    console.log(res)
    return res.data
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message)
  }
}
```

`api.ts`

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
    }
    return config
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
)
export default api
```

`proxy.ts`

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware'
const BACKEND_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_ENDPOINT as string // https://backend-example.com

export default function (app: {
  use: (arg0: string, arg1: import('http-proxy-middleware').RequestHandler) => void
}) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: BACKEND_URL,
      pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/' },
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  )
}
```

I even tried `axios` for that

```
const api = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  proxy: {
     host:'https://backend-example.com',
     port: 80,
  }
})
```

Thanks :)